# when displaying image using php readfile, thin lines appear on the image

Tags: php, image, jpeg, readfile

I am using php's readfile to display jpeg images outside of my sites web root. Unfortunately when I do, some small lines appear on the image. Has anyone noticed this occurring and found a fix? Is there a better function to use rather than readfile?

Thanks for any help.

[image: small line is not on the original]

Live Link: http://s116777.gridserver.com/pop_up_image/editions/00013

You may have to refresh a few times, but they will appear about 30% of the time - as shown below:

[image]

Comment: I can guarantee you that `readfile()` won't add lines into JPEG images. Can you show a live example?

Comment: Have you compared the "readfile'd" image with the original one? Maybe there is some output which causes your lines.

Comment: Hey, I added a live link and another screen shot. I get reports on this from my client, so it isn't just my computer or browser.

Comment: Does this behavior persist in multiple browsers?

Comment: You know I never checked. But it appears to only happen in firefox. So then this is a firefox issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems i can only reproduce this in Firefox. I Would suggest starting a fresh profile on firefox (i think you could do "firefox -P" or use the profile wizard) and seeing if the problem persists. if its fixed it means one of your extensions might be causing some havoc :)

Comment: Yes, unfortunately my client is getting the same thing, and I have to have it work irregardless. So... damn. That screws me up on keeping the files out of the webroot. I guess I'll have to come up with a system where only the public images are copied to a web-accessible folder, then removed.